# Type String Out In TextBox (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trying to make my application make it look as if a string is being typed out into the textbox. My main problem with my code seems to be that the thread.sleep does not sleep for each individual character, just the whole application. For example, if I call the sub with the string "hello", it will stop for 100 milliseconds, and then the TextBox will display "hello" all at once.

```
Sub typeOut(ByVal toType As String)
    toType = toType.ToCharArray()
    For Each letter As Char In toType
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + letter
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are putting the UI thread to sleep before it can display the new character.

Comment: @Plutonix how can i fix this?

Comment: try `TextBox2.Refresh` in the loop

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, figured it out just before i saw this!

Comment: A better way would be to not `Sleep()` on the UI thread at all. If you can make the method `Async`, it would be cleaner to `Await Task.Delay(100)`

Comment: replace `TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + letter
` with `TextBox2.SelectedText = letter`

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks! That worked great along with Plutonix's solution :D

Comment: You won't need a `Refresh` when you program asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ideal job for a Timer. You can even make it so that you can have more than one TextBox being typed at the same time at different speeds.

Demonstration of concept: I placed two TextBoxes and two Buttons on a new Windows Forms project form and used the following code to achieve that:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Class TypeText
        Property Target As TextBox
        Property TextToType As String

        Private tim As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        Private currentChar As Integer

        Private Sub EmitCharacters(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Target.Text &= TextToType.Chars(currentChar)
            currentChar += 1
            If currentChar = TextToType.Length Then
                RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf EmitCharacters
                tim.Dipose()
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub Start()
            AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf EmitCharacters
            tim.Start()
        End Sub

        'TODO: add Stop, Pause, Restart etc. methods if needed

        Public Sub New(target As TextBox, textToType As String, interval As Integer)
            Me.Target = target
            Me.TextToType = textToType
            tim = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
            tim.Interval = interval
            currentChar = 0
        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim typer As New TypeText(TextBox1, "Hello, World!", 200)
        typer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim typer As New TypeText(TextBox2, "This is some other text.", 350)
        typer.Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```